# Wave of values class in AS3. Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, algorithm

The problem with Math.sin() is that I cant figure out a way to control the increment. Still this seems like a lot of code for such a simple concept. Any improvement ideas?

```
package { // by default, iterating the next() function will return 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4, etc

public class valueWave {
    private var maxno,inc,startno,offset,removeDuplicates,internalNum  //internalNum is always>0
    private var goingUp=true
    public var num              //latest value

    public function valueWave($min:Number=0, $max:Number=10, $increment:Number=1, $startno:Number=0, $removeDuplicates=true) {
        if($max<$min){
            trace("valueWave ERROR: max must be greater than min")
            return
        }
        maxno=$max-$min
        inc=$increment
        startno=$startno
        internalNum=$startno
        num=$startno
        offset=$min
        removeDuplicates=$removeDuplicates
    }

    public function next(){
        if(maxno==0){return(0);} //disable if max and min are the same
        if(goingUp){//going up:
            if(internalNum <= maxno-inc){
                internalNum+=inc
            }else{//invert:
                goingUp=false
                if(removeDuplicates) internalNum-=inc
            }
        }else{//going down:
            if(internalNum >= inc){
                internalNum-=inc
            }else{//invert:
                goingUp=true
                if(removeDuplicates) internalNum+=inc
            }
        }
        upd()
        return(num)
    }

    public function reset(){
        internalNum=startno
        goingUp=true
    }

    private function upd(){
        num=internalNum+offset
    }

}
}
```

### UPDATE:

Final solution, packaged into a simple class with instructions can be found here:
http://blog.crondesign.com/2011/07/as3-wave-of-values-class-function.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Math.abs((internalNum++ % 18) - 9) + 1
```

This will map the integers to the sequence you need.

And here's a general version:

```
value = Math.abs((internalNum % (2*(max-min))) - (max-min)) + min;
internalNum += increment;
```

Just be wary of how the divisibility of `(max-min)` by `increment` affects your values.  The starting value of `internalNum` will determine which sequence the algorithm generates when `increment != 1 or -1`.

Comment: Brilliant! I wish I'd thought of that! Thanks a lot @merv

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to work through the math right now, but you want to read up on [Recurrence Relationships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).  That sequence isn't that bad to generate.  There are two parts.  One generates the sequence of numbers, the other is a `(-1)^n` term to handle the up/down portion.

A decent algorithms book should cover this.  The standard text is [Introduction To Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).  Every programmer should own a copy.